# How to set the background image in a chart in CRM 2011 XML

Tags: xml, image, charts, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Im trying to add an image to the background of a radar chart in crm 2011 using XML. I've tried this:

```
<ChartAreas>  
         <ChartArea BackImage="c:\test\wheeltest1.jpg" BorderColor="White" BorderDashStyle="Solid">
```

Where the image is on the root of the application server but I get the following error:

> An Error Occurred Whilst the Chart Was Rendering

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?